# Placing percentages in boxes and adding subheadings in likert module of R

Tags: r, plot, statistics, percentage

Using the `likert` package of R (more information: http://jason.bryer.org/likert/) to create these graphs which uses `ggplot2`.

Here is some example code to generate a graph using `likert` in R.

```
require(likert)

data(pisaitems)

items28 <- pisaitems[, substr(names(pisaitems), 1, 5) == "ST24Q"]

l28 <- likert(items28)

plot(l28)
```

Here is an example of what I want the output to show instead:

[image]

Firstly, I was wanting to add percentages into each box in the likert scale to represent the amount, instead of just in the middle like it currently offers. I have looked through the source code on github and can't understand how he does this.

Secondly, I was wondering it it were possible to have a subheading over each side of the middle divide to say "percentage of very low/low" and "percentage of high/very high" over on top of the graph which stays in relation to the rest of the plot.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To add the percentages you just need to set the argument `plot.percents` to `TRUE`. I don't know a good solution for the subheading, but you can play around with the `ggtitle` and `theme` functions of the `ggplot2` package. Here is one idea:

```
plot(l28, plot.percents = TRUE) + 
ggtitle("Percentage of Strongly disagree/Disagree  Percentage of Strongly agree/Agree") +
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.45, size = 10))
```